# Referencing columns by assigned name in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to create column names for easy reference, That way I can just call the name from the rest of the program instead of having to know which column is where in terms of placement. The `from_` column array is coming up empty. I am new to numpy so I am just wondering how this is done. Changing of data type for columns 5 and 6 was successful though.

```
def array_setter():
        import os
        import glob
        import numpy as np
        os.chdir\
        ('C:\Users\U2970\Documents\Arcgis\Text_files\Data_exports\North_data_folder')
        for file in glob.glob('*.TXT'):
                reader = open(file)
                headerLine = reader.readlines()
        for col in headerLine:
                valueList = col.split(",")
                data = np.array([valueList])
                from_ = np.array(data[1:,[5]],dtype=np.float32)
                # trying to assign a name to columns for easy reference
                to = np.array(data[1:,[6]],dtype=np.float32)
                if data[:,[1]] == 'C005706N':
                        if data[:,[from_] < 1.0]:
                                print data[:,[from_]]
array_setter()
```

Comment: Is the first line from the file(s) column names?  What about the rest of the data?  A mix of string names and floats?  `np.genfromtxt` might be a useful reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to index array columns by name name, I would recommend turning the array into a pandas dataframe. For example,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['f', 's'])
print df['f']
```

The nice part of this approach is that the arrays still maintain all their structure but you also get all the optimized indexing/slicing/etc. capabilities of pandas. For example, if you wanted to find elements of 'f' that corresponded to elements of 's' being equal to some value `a`, then you could use `loc`

```
a = 2
print df.loc[df['s']==2, 'f']
```

Check out the pandas docs for different ways to use the DataFrame object. Or you could read the book by Wes McKinney (pandas creator), *Python for Data Analysis*. Even though it was written for an older version of pandas, it's a great starting point and will set you in the right direction.

Comment: I gave you the answer credit on that one. Thank you very much! Now how can i do conditionals on the float data in one of the columns?

Comment: Glad to help! I extended the answer to address what I think you're asking. Hopefully it helps!